# discord bot not responding and says Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: replit

I have been trying to get the bot to respond but it won't here is the code

```js
client.on("messageCreate", message => {    

  if(message.content === "ping") {    

    message.chanel.send("pong")    
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a "channel", not "chanel"